# Windows XP as VM on an old computer

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine

I have this old machine (a Powermate ML5 PC) with these specs:

```
OS Name: Microsoft Windows XP Professional
Version: 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600
OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
System Manufacturer: NEC Computers International
System Model: POWERMATE ML5
System Type: X86-based PC
Processor: x86 Family 15 Model 2 Stepping 9 GenuineIntel ~2806 Mhz
BIOS Version/Date: American Megatrends Inc. 0007/234A0700, 11/26/2003
SMBIOS Version: 2.3
Windows Directory: C:\WINDOWS
System Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale: United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer: Version = "5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-2111)"
Time Zone: Arabian Standard Time
Total Physical Memory: 1,024.50 MB
Available Physical Memory: 133.29 MB
Total Virtual Memory: 2.00 GB
Available Virtual Memory: 1.96 GB
Page File Space: 2.39 GB
Page File: C:\pagefile.sys
```

What options do I have if I need to have Windows XP as guest OS in a virtual machine on this old hardware? Especially is having Windows XP in VirtualBox on Linux feasible here?

Comment: You should be able just to load a Window XP .iSO into the VM and install XP

Comment: OK. But my question relates more to the part of memory requirement issues of both OSes plus the virtualization software on such an old machine. Would the old thing be able to sustain all that, given that I have to install additional software on XP?

Comment: There are two models of the NEC PowerMate ML5, the PowerMate ML5 Slim and the laptop. Which model do you have?

Comment: @karel I have the PowerMate ML5 Slim model. OT: Why has the question been downvoted?

Comment: In my view your question is a subtle question that hinges on the cost and availability of DDR RAM to improve your VM's performance. The NEC PowerMate ML5 Slim can take a maximum of 1GB or 2GB RAM, depending on the model. The price of DDR RAM dropped at about the same time as Windows XP support ended. I can think of no legitimate reason why anyone would downvote your question except for the mercy factor that support for XP has ended and using XP even in a VM is a security risk. Lubuntu has similar systems requirements to XP, if you're concerned about the security risk, and it's free software.

Comment: @karel I'm trying to use the system as it is AFAP. I already have Linux-lite in dual-boot, that's why I put the VirtualBox suggestion. The only reason I must use xp is there are some legacy software and hardware that I must deal with (and yes, i searched for linux-based alternatives; those replaceable have been, there are which are not yet available and there are some which won't be available. Its for the last two that I'm stuck to xp)